# How to replace a string by using part of the string in the same line?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have a file like the following on a Linux machine, and the `gene_id` is wrong. So I would like to replace the string `"PB"` in the `gene_id` with the `transcript_id` from the same line.

```
$ cat try.gff

transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.66";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.59";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.40";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.30";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.20";
transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.28.309";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.58.900";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.10000.1001";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.19897.1087541";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.11";
```

Expected result

```
transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.66";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.59";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.40";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.30";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.20";
transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.28"; transcript_id "PB.28.309";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.58"; transcript_id "PB.58.900";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.10000"; transcript_id "PB.10000.1001";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.19897"; transcript_id "PB.19897.1087541";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.11";
```

I managed to get the right text for replacement with the code `awk -F";" '{gsub(" transcript_id ","");print $2}' try.gff | sed 's/"//g' | cut -d '.' -f 1,2`

```
PB.1
PB.1
PB.1
PB.1
PB.1
PB.28
PB.58
PB.10000
PB.19897
PB.1
```

How can I replace the `"PB"` in the `gene_id` part?

Comment: Is the file you have shown your complete, actual file (I assume not) or a really representative example? Specifically, will the transcript_id always have two dots? Will there ever be anything on the line after the transcript_id? Will the gene_id ever not match the first two letters of the transcript_id (e.g., `gene_id "AB"; transcript_id "CD.1.59";`? If so, what would you want to happen?

Comment: What kind of transcript IDs are those? I've never seen these identifiers before and can't find them on NCBI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any `sed` in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*gene_id "\)[^"]*\(.*"\([^.]*\.[^.]*\).*\)/\1\3\2/' try.gff
transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.66";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.59";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.40";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.30";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.20";
transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.28"; transcript_id "PB.28.309";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.58"; transcript_id "PB.58.900";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.10000"; transcript_id "PB.10000.1001";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.19897"; transcript_id "PB.19897.1087541";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.11";
```

In the regexp part every `\(` starts a capture group that's terminated by the matching `\)`. In the replacement part every `\<digit>` refers to the string that matched the regexp segment within the capture group. So `\1` refers to the string that matched `\(.*gene_id "\)` and so on. The rest is just basic regexp segments (e.g. `.*` means 0 or more repetitions of any character, `[^"]*` means zero or more reps of any char except `"`, and `\.` means a literal `.`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please explain a bit the command? I was trying to search how to write those complicated text in the sed command, but I didn't find the explanation...

Comment: You're welcome. I added an explanation to my answer. Let me know if you have any specific questions after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/"[A-Z]\+\("[^"]*\(.*\)\..*\)/\2\1/' input_file
transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.66";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.59";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.40";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.30";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.20";
transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.28"; transcript_id "PB.28.309";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.58"; transcript_id "PB.58.900";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.10000"; transcript_id "PB.10000.1001";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.19897"; transcript_id "PB.19897.1087541";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.11";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*The simple way (assumes TSV file like `gff` format):*

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = lines>>.split("\t").flat; @a[7,17,27...*] = @a[9,19,29...*];    \
         @a[7,17,27...*].=comb(/ <alpha>+ \. <digit>+ /).=map(q["] ~ * ~ q["]);  \
         .put for @a.rotor(10)>>.join("\t");'
```

The code above simply splits each `line` on `\t` tabs, and `flat`tens elements to make a completely linear array (10 rows x 10 columns = 100 elements). Each 8th-column `gene_id` (zero-index = 7) is overwritten by the 10th-column `transcript_id` (zero-index = 9). Raku figures out the remainder of the indexing sequence, provided you give it enough hints.

Once the full `transcript_id` has been copied, it's simple enough to `comb` out `<alpha>+ \. \d+` the desired characters, `q["] ~ * ~ q["]` wrap them in quotation marks, and `rotor` each 10 elements to reconstruct the 10 x 10 table.

---

*The purely regex way (harder):*

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's/ <?after ^ .+? gene_id \s \" > (.+?)  (\"\; \s transcript_id \s \")  (<alpha>+ \. \d+) <?before \.> /$2$1$2/;' try.gff
```

OR

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's/  <?after ^ .+? gene_id \s \c[QUOTATION MARK] > (.+?)  (\c[QUOTATION MARK] \; \s transcript_id \s \")  (<alpha>+ \. \d+) <?before \.> /$2$1$2/;' try.gff
```

Here Raku's `-pe` autoprinting linewise flags are used, in conjunction with the familiar `s///` substitution operator. Five regex atoms are searched for and three are captured with parentheses:

1. a zerowidth positive look-behind `<?after … >` targeting the `^` start-of-string up to `gene_id \s \"` (includes trailing whitespace and quotation mark),
2. [captured as `$0`] a non-greedy `.+?` any-character one-or-more times which is the to-be-discarded `gene_id` itself,
3. [captured as `$1`] the text comprising `transcript_id` section of the line (including surrounding whitespace and punctuation),
4. [captured as `$2`] the desired `<alpha>+ \. \d+` portion of the `transcript_id`, then
5. a zerowidth positive look-ahead `<?before … >`, which stops the preceding capture before the second `\.` dot.

Finally in the replacement, the captured `$2` is used to replace the `$0` capture. The `$1` and `$2` captures are restored to their normal positions.

Sample Input:

```
transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.66";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.59";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.40";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.30";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.20";
transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.28.309";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.58.900";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.10000.1001";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.19897.1087541";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB"; transcript_id "PB.1.11";
```

Sample Output:

```
transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.66";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.59";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.40";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.30";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.20";
transcript  30351   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.28"; transcript_id "PB.28.309";
exon    30351   31677   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.58"; transcript_id "PB.58.900";
exon    31758   31871   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.10000"; transcript_id "PB.10000.1001";
exon    31968   32178   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.19897"; transcript_id "PB.19897.1087541";
exon    32257   32332   .   +   .   gene_id "PB.1"; transcript_id "PB.1.11";
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org